# Percentage sign (%) in Python string without %%

Tags: python, mysql

I've got the following piece of Python code:

```
statement = statement + " OR (TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, (str_to_date( (SELECT tijd FROM Metingen WHERE SensorID='" + sensor_id + "' ORDER BY MetingID DESC LIMIT 1), '%%d-%%m-%%Y %%H:%%i' )), NOW()) >= " + waarde + " AND MetingID=(SELECT metingID FROM Metingen WHERE SensorID='" + sensor_id + "' ORDER BY metingID DESC LIMIT 1)"
```

I'm trying to use the str_to_date MySQL function, but therefor I need to use the percentage sign in the MySQL query, which is being generated in Python. I know using `%%` should solve this problem, but when I do that both percentage signs get printed into the query and the query won't work.

Comment: ***DO NOT USE THIS CODE IN PRODUCTION*** IT IS VULNERABLE TO SQL INJECTION!

Comment: The code will only be ran on our own system, no one besides us will get this program or access to it so I pretend it's safe?

Comment: in python you should not create a string like that, use `format`

Comment: @Rick the question is not where the code run not who access the program but where the values (`sensor_id` etc) come from. Also, correct use of the db-api prevents escaping problems, and finally, it makes for much more readable (hence maintainable) code. You have no reason to stick to manual string concatenation and at least three very good reasons to use the db-api as intended.

Comment: Oh and yes: this _might_ solve your problem too, so give it a try <g>

Comment: When you pass parameters to your query the `%%` are converted to `%` (assuming you are using `pymysql.paramstyle='pyformat'`).  Since you are not passing any parameters this step is skipped and you statement is never processed to its final form.  The best thing to do is to embrace the correct way of doing things and pass `waarde` and `sensor_id` as a parameters.  If you aren't going to do that stop doubling the percent signs. (But really, don't do that.  Make a habit of being safe. It looks cleaner as well.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I have hard-coded SQL queries in my code I like to put them in a multi-line string. (see the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.2/tutorial/introduction.html#strings) on strings)

```
QUERY = """
{prefix} 
OR (
    TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, 
    (str_to_date((
        SELECT tijd 
        FROM Metingen 
        WHERE SensorID='{sensor_id}' 
        ORDER BY MetingID DESC LIMIT 1), 
    '%d-%m-%Y %H:%i' )), 
    NOW()) >= {waarde} 
AND 
    MetingID=(
        SELECT metingID 
        FROM Metingen 
        WHERE SensorID='{sensor_id}' 
        ORDER BY metingID DESC LIMIT 1)
""".strip()

statement = QUERY.format(
    prefix=statement,
    sensor_id=sensor_id,
    waarde=waarde)
```

Comment: There's a bracket missing after `ORDER BY metingID DESC LIMIT 1)`, but with that one added this works. Thanks!